# Есть ли возможность подключить IPhone удалённо к маку для тестирования приложения в xCode?

Tags: xcode, iphone, mac, teamviewer

Может вопрос конечно не очень умный) Но вдруг есть такой способ. 
У меня ситуация: у меня компьютер под управлением Windows, у меня есть айфон. У другого человека мак, на котором установлен xCode. Есть ли способ при котором я могу подключить свой айфон через свой компьютер и чтобы на маке удалённо он воспринимался как если бы был подключён к нему напрямую?

Может есть что-то наподобие тимвьювера?

Comment: Есть remote usb

Comment: @Alex78191 большое спасибо. Попробую.

Comment: USB Network Gate, FlexiHub, VirtualHere